# Openlayers 3.5.0: Problems with GeoJSON in IE11

Tags: geojson, openlayers, internet-explorer

I seem to have a problem with loading a geojson-file as source for a layer in IE11 using openlayers 3.5.0. IE11 throws an error without any description. The problem seems to occur when the geojson is set as a vector-source for an imagevector layer.

Both Chrome and Firefox do not have this problem and renders my map as desired.

A little piece of my code:

```
var groupedData = groupByData(data, level, json.visualConfig.measure);
var minValue = getMinValue(groupedData, 'total');
var maxValue = getMaxValue(groupedData, 'total');
var scaleStepSize = 0;
var scaleSize = json.visualConfig.scaleSize;
var newColors = [];
if(maxValue < scaleSize) {
    scaleSize = maxValue;
    for (var i = colors.length - scaleSize; i < colors.length; i++) {
        newColors.push(colors[i]);
    }
} else {
    newColors = colors;
}
var scaleStepSize = Math.ceil((maxValue - minValue) / scaleSize);

// Reset Extent
featuresExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

// Layer
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: file,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', projection: 'EPSG:3857'})
        }),
        style: (function () {
                return function (feature, resolution) {
                    formatScale(minValue, scaleStepSize, newColors, json.visualConfig.measure + ' per ' + name);
                    var color = '#ffffff';
                    groupedData.forEach(function(vData){ 
                            if(vData.dimensionValue == feature.get(reference) && vData.dimensionValue != null) {
                                    for(var i = 0; i < newColors.length; i++) {
                                        var startValue = minValue + (i * scaleStepSize);
                                        var endValue = minValue + ((i + 1) * scaleStepSize);
                                        if(vData.total >= startValue && vData.total <= endValue) { 
                                            color = newColors[i];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    feature.set('measure', measure);
                                    feature.set('measureValue', vData.total);
                                    ol.extent.extend(featuresExtent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
                            }
                    });
                    var newStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
                        fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                            color : color
                        }),
                        stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color : '#C3C3C3',
                            width : 1
                        })
                    })];
                    return newStyle;
                }
            })()
    }),
    minResolution: minZoom,
    maxResolution: ((layers.length == 1) ? 20000 : maxZoom), // eerste laag mag altijd naar maxResolutie = 20000
    opacity: 0.8,
    level: level,
    reference: reference,
    name: name
});
```

Comment: Sometimes IE throws errors when there's a comma at the last object's position; Post your entire object code.

Comment: force the Legacy mode (compatibility mode) in IE11 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Legacy mode did not do the trick. I have updated my question with some more code. Btw IE I have loaded the ol.debug.js file and IE throws the following error: "File: ol-debug.js, Line: 65460, Column: 7". When I load ol.js it throws "Invalid character. File ol.js, line 493, column 286'.

Comment: Looks like IE11 has issues with the JSON object. When I modify the ol-debug.js script at the position as descrebid in my comment above a litte so it does not throw an error but it does log to console with output. I get an invalid json string with part of my json object.

Comment: ***************

Comment: It is definitely aJSON parsing isue in IE11. Not sure why unfornutaly. If I create a small HTML file which parses the same JSON-string it's al fine. Looks like OL 3.5.0 parses the JSON different than JSON.parse()

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Somehow IE has problems with GeoJSON file containing characters like à or â etc.... Replacing those characters in the GeoJSON with normal characters (like a) does the trick.

Chrome and FF seems to have no issues at all with these kind of characters.